# additional services ... or the additional services

Tags: definite-article

I have written down two similar sentences below.

(1) According to our store policy, customers have to pay more for additional services they may need to upgrade their computers.

(2) According to our store policy, customers have to pay more for **the** additional services they may need to their computer.

I am not sure if I need the definite article "the".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definite articles are not generally necessary with plurals. Where a singular, countable noun is used, you generally need an article or determiner; if it is not specific, it will usually be an indefinite article. Where it is plural, you don't *need* an article or determiner, but can use one where it is appropriate. A definite article is particularly dubious in this case because it's only a case that they **may** be needed.

You can have a word there, if you want - you can use ***any***, which fits well with the *may* and the fact that the nature of the services are unknown at the time of writing (as they will vary between customers). However, the actual meaning of *any* may be assumed without actually writing it. Whether you include it or not is largely a matter of style.

Comment: I like your clear, step-by-step explanation. You have helped me understand when to use the definite article in the correct way. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the question and the statements the article "the" is not needed.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.